# How to download source and implement Google OpenID+OAuth Hybrid protocol?

Tags: php, openid, oauth

I want to build a website that allows user sign in with Openid, especially Google account. I wanna use Google Federated Login with Hybrid protocol. I found that link:
http://code.google.com/intl/vi-VN/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html
But I didnt find any link to download the source code. Anybody can help me? Thank you so much.
P/S: I only can use php, plz help me with php source code :D. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenID+OAuth hybrid protocol is just OpenID with a very simple extension on top.  Get yourself a decent PHP OpenID library and find/implement the very simple OAuth extension and you're good to go.

Well, you'll also need a library to perform the OAuth signing with the access token.